# File path in php require

Tags: php, relative-path

I've inherited some code:

```
include('../cfg/db_setup.php');
require('./fpdf/fpdf.php');
```

I know that ../cfg means start in the current directory, then go up one level and down into the cfg dir. What does the ./fpdf mean? I've never seen a single dot slash used in a file path, and can't seem to find the fpdf directory anywhere on our server, but the code is working so apparently it's there somewhere.

Comment: current directory. btw this is not a good practice for PHP includes. You should use include (dirname(__FILE__)."../cfg/db_setup.php") to provide absolute paths, not those related to the current directory (that might change by many means)

Comment: I'm aware of that, thanks. Like I said, this is code I inherited. I need to find all the referenced files before I can start dealing with absolute paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is defined as the current folder.

So, if the PHP script is located at `/path/to/script/`, then the second statement will look for `/path/to/script/fpdf/fpdf.php`

Comment: Thank you. I'm not used to dealing with relative paths.

Answer (score 22):

Just a note.

Relative paths don't are relative to the current include_path.

Relative paths, such as . or ../ are relative to the current **working** directory. The working directory is different if you run a script on CGI or command line or if a script is included by another script in another directory.

Therefore theoretically is not possible to be sure where these paths are pointing to without to know the context :P

To be sure, if PHP < 5.3:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../cfg/db_setup.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/fpdf/fpdf.php');
```

If PHP >= 5.3:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/../cfg/db_setup.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/fpdf/fpdf.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

./ is the current directory.  ./fpdf/ should be on the same path as the including file, or somewhere on the off the php include_path.

Answer (score 0):

`./` - this means in the current path